# Does restkit for ios support both an in-memory domain object as well as a core-data backed NSManaged object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

It's unclear to me if RESTKit has native support for syncing domain objects with persisted objects in core data.
That is, in my app all parts use domain objects such as a Person object (subclass of NSObject).  It's what's stored in memory.  A Person core data entity (subclass of NSManagedObject) is what is saved to the phone.  I want to have that extra layer rather than using NSManagedObjects throughout my app.

So does restkit do this?

```
json ---> Person (NSObject) ---> Person core data entity (NSManagedObject)
```

or does it go from json ----> NSManagedObject, and cut out the "middle man" Person object entirely and we're all passing around NSManagedObjects throughout an app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. Restkit will do either

```
JSON => Person (NSObject)
```

or

```
JSON => Person entity (NSManagedObject)
```

and return the results to you / save the result to the data store. What you do with it after that is up to you.

You haven't given a reason for not passing the `NSManagedObject` subclasses 'around' your app, but you might want to consider using [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) and cutting out your middle objects and using multiple classes in your object inheritance to separate out the Core Data parts from your custom modifications.